# How set up ts-transformer-minify-privates with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I want use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-minify-privates on Angular project.

I'm tried:

Install dependecies:

```
npm install ts-transformer-minify-privates --save-dev
npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save-dev
npm install ts-loader --save-dev
```

edit angular.json

```json
  "projects": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "custom-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Add custom-webpack.config.js

```js
// webpack.config.js
var minifyPrivatesTransformer = require('ts-transformer-minify-privates').default;

module.exports = (config, options) => {
  if (config.module && config.module.rules) {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader', // or 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        options: {
          getCustomTransformers: program => ({
            before: [
              minifyPrivatesTransformer(program)
            ]
          })
        }
      }
    );
  }
  return config;
}
```

edit tsconfig.ts

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "ts-transformer-minify-privates"
      }
    ]
}
```

RUN BUILD

```
npm run build
```

but private field aren't minified... :(

Comment: This is why I believe Angular 2+ to be evil.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ahahahah that's true